# Add features to tfidfTransformer in scikitlearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, text-extraction, grid-search, countvectorizer

I try to add features in order to classify document. But my question is how can add features if the size of my matrix is not corresponding with the number of sample. Here my estimator

```
class Add(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        print(type(X))
        print('Dans Add X vaut:', X.shape)
        return X

    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        return self

pipeline = Pipeline([
       ('vect', TfidfVectorizer()),
       ('add_features', Add()),
       ('clf', SGDClassifier())
])
parameters = {'vect__max_features': (3000,5000)}
data  = load_files('./HO_without_tag', categories=None)
X , Y = (data.data, data.target)
print(len(X), len(Y))
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid = parameters, n_jobs = 1, verbose = 1000)
grid_search.fit(X,Y).transform(X)
```

But in my result, I don't print everything...

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 1 candidates, totalling 3 fits
[CV] vect__max_features=3000
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
Dans Addned X vaut: (323, 3000)
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
Dans Addned X vaut: (163, 3000)
.......
```

I don't understand what does it means (323, 3000) and (163, 3000)???

Normally I have 486 documents (file). If I want to add some features in my transform method, I just need to concatenate the array given by the first pipeline tdfIdfVectorizer ((486, 3000) in my understanding) to my new array of features with this shape (486, number of my features).
For now, I can not personnalize my transform method because, I have at this time incompatible row dimension.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: have you tried FeatureUnion?

Comment: Yes but I have a row incompatible dimension. So It is why I try to do in a basic way. Just vectorize with tdfidf, add new columns and classified.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what does "incompatible row dimension mean". "Row dimension" is just a number of examples to predict / to train on. Transformers and estimators must handle any row dimension. With grid search data is split into two parts, that's why you have 323+163=486

Comment: OK. So I was considering all the data (486 documents) as my training data. If Gridsearch split the data.... It is make no sense to add a new array with this  shape (486, n_features) to X (only a part of sample).

Comment: In fact gridsearchCV and featureunion must be used together carefully... If I understand well.  Your comments answer also to my previous post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456377/featureunion-in-scikit-klearn-and-incompatible-row-dimension?rq=1
Thanks a lot!!